# Custom mail server does not receive mail from outside

Tags: ubuntu, email, sendinblue

I am using Brevo / SendInBlue as an external SMTP as it can be found on the Internet (e-g: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/postfix-smtp#ftoc-heading-7).

My issue is that I can send email but I am not able to receive it.

postfix main.cf :

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 3.6 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 3.6



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level=may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mydomain
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, mydomain, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = [smtp-relay.sendinblue.com]:587
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128, 192.168.1.86/24
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

#Config relay
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = static:user:key #hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd in future
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = mydomain
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes

smtp_sasl_security_option = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_security_level = may
header_size_limit = 4096000
home_mailbox = Maildir/
#transport_maps = static:smtp:[smtp-relay.sendinblue.com]:587
```

Where mydomain is my dns adress (e-g: example.com), user and key are the parameters given from sendinblue.

I am not receiving any mail sent from a local mail adress either.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: DNS MX records are ```example.com``` and ```mail.example.com```